# How to run this c++ project in windows 10?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Iam trying to run one c++ project form github to run on my windows 10. Please help me which IDE should i use to run and how to run?

Presently am using Atom but am not able to download gpp-compiler for atom

I have tried to add gpp-compiler to Atom and then run from Atom , but its not getting downloaded to Atom. Iam looking for new IDE suggestions to run it better

this is the github link `https://github.com/usnistgov/NFIQ2`

SO am basically looking for an IDE where i can run and see the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don;t think any IDE for Windows will help. From projects page:

"A supported operating system:

RHEL/CentOS >= 6.x

Ubuntu

macOS >= 10.11"

Perhaps you could do something with Cygwin (no, it is not IDE), but it seems to be quite a work.

Comment: what about this? https://bitbucket.org/trago/fingerproc/src/master/nfiq/  its a c code

Comment: There is no page saying where it can be used, there are few concerns that make me doubt: `Host System: GNU GCC/GMAKE GENERIC (UNIX)` - entry in every Makefile file and some non-Windows-standard include files like `usebsd.h`, etc.

Comment: so basically not for windows?

Comment: @ramytati No Windows directly, but you can run a Linux virtual machine on Windows.

Comment: actually i need to convert this into golang

Comment: i only need algorithm to get quality score of fingerprint